# (node) warning: possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 message listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit

Tags: python, node.js

Whenever I am running the following code I am getting the error

```
(node) warning: possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 message listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit.
```

The code:

```
function compute() {
     var PythonShell = require('python-shell');
            var options = {
                scriptPath: '/home/pi/projectFinal/nodejsControllingServo/sensorTest'
            };
            var pyshell = new PythonShell('sensor.py',options);
            var eventsEmitter = require("events").EventEmitter;



    pyshell.on('message', function (message) {
                        myValueList [counter] = message;
                        counter=counter+1;
                    });
    pyshell.end(function (err) {
                        if (err) throw err;

                        for ( var i = 4; i < myValueList.length; i++) {
                             console.log ("My value : " + myValueList[i]);   
                    });


    sleep.usleep(5000);
            process.nextTick(compute);
        }
        compute();
```

What could be the possible solution so that I can get rid of memory leak? 
Thanks in advance